# Python file pointer

Tags: python

In python file handling why we need to close() or discard pointer reference even when we are in read mode.
reading don't do any changes in file which are required to be saved by dereferncing file pointer.

Comment: because some OSes lock the file when opened for reading, for instance.

Comment: A file-handle is a resource in the system, and a *finite* resource. Sooner or later your system could run out of file-handles if you don't close your files. Furthermore, when you don't need the file anymore, and don't close it, how would others that want to write to the file be able to open it? Some operating systems don't allow that.

Comment: You can avoid having to call `close()` by using `with open("file.txt", "r") as f:`. Doing it this way automatically closes the file for you.